# How can I prettily invoke a method whose name is in a string?

Tags: raku

In Perl 5, I could say

```
my $meth = 'halt_and_catch_fire';
my $result = $obj->$meth();
```

This is very convenient for iterating over a list of method names to do stuff.  I've managed to get as far as figuring out that in Perl 6 I *can't* just say

```
my $result = $obj.$meth();
```

One thing that *does* work is

```
my $result = $obj.^can($meth)[0]($obj);
```

But that seems completely terrible.  How should I be going about this?

Comment: If the strings that you use as method names are string constants appearing somewhere in your source code, you can probably replace them with expressions that return callable method objects instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, if `$meth` contains a (reference to a) Callable object such as a method then you can write what you wrote and the Rakudo compiler will accept it:

```
my $result = $obj.$meth;   # call the Callable in $meth, passing $obj as invocant
my $result = $obj.$meth(); # same
```

Rakudo will complain (at compile time) if $meth isn't a Callable.

It sounds like what you want is to be able to just provide the method name as a string. In that case put that string in $meth and write:

```
my $result = $obj."$meth"(); # use quotes if $meth is method name as a string
my $result = $obj."$meth";   # SORRY! Rakudo complains if you don't use parens
```

For more info see [the *Fancy method calls* section of the *Objects* design document](http://design.raku.org/S12.html#Fancy_method_calls).